# constants in assembly

Tags: assembly, disassembly

Wikipedia says:

> Assembly language source code
>   generally permits the use of constants
>   and programmer comments. These are
>   usually removed from the assembled
>   machine code by the assembler. If so,
>   a disassembler operating on the
>   machine code would produce disassembly
>   lacking these constants and comments;
>   the disassembled output becomes more
>   difficult for a human to interpret
>   than the original annotated source
>   code.

it's understandable of comments, but why does assembler remove constants??
Are they used in computation, aren't they?? 
How can CPU compute without constant values??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a named constant, it directly uses its value.

Answer (score 2):

I guess they mean *definitions* of constants.
The definitions are removed; the constants of course stay.

Answer (score 0):

A constant would normally be defined by an '[assembler directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language#Assembly_directives)'. It tells the assembler to associate a label with a constant number, for example:

```
my_constant equ 42
```

This doesn't generate any machine code until it is used in the program somewhere:

```
lodi,r0 my_constant
```